# jquery - using .closest()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stucking with jQuery where I need to use closest to get the .text() of the wanted element.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="endorse-set">
<div class="endorse">
<span class="keyword" id="keyword-1">web developer</span>
<textarea class="comment" id="comment-1"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="endorse-button" id="endorse-button-1" value="Endorse">
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<div class="endorse">
<span class="keyword" id="keyword-2">web designer</span>
<textarea class="comment" id="comment-2"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="endorse-button" id="endorse-button-2" value="Endorse">
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<div class="endorse">
<span class="keyword" id="keyword-3">Entrepreneur</span>
<textarea class="comment" id="comment-3"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="endorse-button" id="endorse-button-3" value="Endorse">
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
</div>
```

I need to get the `.text()` i.e. **web designer or web developer or entrepreneur** and the `.comment` value, when the user clicks `.endorse-button`

I tried like this and failed:

```
$(".endorse-button").click(function(){        
        var keyword = $(this).closest('span.keyword').text();
        var comment = $(this).closest('textarea.comment').val();
        alert(keyword);
        alert(comment);
});
```

I'm getting nothing. Could you help me?

P.S. I'm new to jQuery!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `closest` method looks at *ancestor* elements (e.g. the parent `div.endorse`, and the parent of that etc). The elements in question are *siblings*, so you can use the [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method:

```
$(".endorse-button").click(function(){        
    var keyword = $(this).siblings('span.keyword').text();
    var comment = $(this).siblings('textarea.comment').val();
    alert(keyword);
    alert(comment);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would use `.closest()` in this situation:

```
$('.endorse-button').click(function(){
    var endorse = $(this).closest('.endorse'),
        keyword = endorse.find('span.keyword').text(),
        comment = endorse.find('textarea.comment').val();
    alert(keyword);
    alert(comment);
});
```